# Can't resolve mLatLng in Center of the circle

Tags: android, google-maps

In my Android Map I simply draw a circle and I need the current location to be the center of the circle and when change the location of the device, the circle must be rechanged and load markers again inside the circle.

Here is my code.

First I simply hard coded some 5 places.

```
LatLng POINTA = new LatLng(6.9192, 79.8950);
LatLng POINTB = new LatLng(6.9006, 79.8533);
LatLng POINTC = new LatLng(6.9147, 79.8778);
LatLng POINTD = new LatLng(6.9036, 79.9547);
LatLng POINTE = new LatLng(6.8397, 79.8758);
```

Then here is the place I draw the circle and load markers.

```
public static boolean isMyLocationSet = false; // Get Current location ass default location

@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

    isMyLocationSet=false; // Get Current location ass default location

    Location target = new Location("target");

    for(LatLng point : new LatLng[]{POINTA,POINTB,POINTC,POINTD,POINTE}){

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);

        LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location currentLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng mLatLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                .center(new LatLng(mLatLng))
                .radius(10000)
                .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
                .strokeWidth(2));


        target.setLatitude(point.latitude);
        target.setLongitude(point.longitude);

        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));

        float[] distance = new float[2];

        if(location.distanceTo(target) <  10000) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        }

        else {
            marker.remove();
        }


    }

}
```

Here I cannot resolve mLatLng in `center(new LatLng(mLatLng))` It says

> Latlng(double, double) in Latlng cannot be applied to (com.google.andrdoid.gms.maps.model.Latlng)

What should I do for this and Is there anything I did wrong with the code?

Comment: In `center()` just give `mLatLng` as parameter, insted of `new LatLng(mLatLng)`

Comment: Its working. Thnaks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you put LatLng object in create new LatLng class object

so given this type of message.Pls use only object as parameter

like

```
LatLng mLatLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(mLatLng)
            .radius(10000)
            .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
            .strokeWidth(2));
```

OR

```
Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .radius(10000)
            .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
            .strokeWidth(2));
```